# Взять значения по индексам

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть расчетная векторная величина `sum_concentrat` взятая из `df_full`.

пример:
`sum_concentrat = df_full[1]+df_full[2]+df_full[3]+df_full[4]`

есть нулевые значения данного показателя.

**ВОПРОС:** Как убрать строки с нулевыми значениями `sum_concentrat` не создовая дополнительного столбца в `df_full`. Нужно именно по индексам. Т.к через создания отдельного столбца я знаю как.

Comment: Ну обычным образом по маске `df_full.loc[sum_concentrat != 0]`, либо я не понял вопроса

Comment: ну приведите пример исходных данных, sum_concentrat и желаемого результата.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индексы вообще не нужны, фильтруйте просто по булевой маске, которую можно сделать из вашего вектора, не создавая для этого отдельный столбец:

```py
df_full = df_full.loc[sum_concentrat != 0]
```

В `sum_concentrat` у вас такая же `pandas.Series`, как и в любом столбце датафрейма, поэтому это работает совершенно таким же образом, как если бы вы накладывали условие на столбец датафрейма. И `sum_concentrat != 0` - это тоже `pandas.Series`, только булевского типа.

Comment: Индекс нужен был что бы из другой таблице убрать строки. Спасибо. Через вашу маску получилось.

Comment: @VANjKE С индексами надо вообще осторожнее. В другой таблице могут быть другие индексы.

Comment: А можете тогда подсказать как сделать по общему столбцу date. В обоих таблицах он есть. Через индексы не получилось)

Comment: Что-то типа `df2.loc[df2.date == df1.loc[sum_concentrat != 0, 'date']]`

Comment: не получается. Ошибку выдает. Я в итоге столбец `sum_concentrat_final_outpu`создал в df_full, иначе общего столбца с датой не будет.

`df_test = df_test.loc[df_test['date'] == df_full.loc['sum_concentrat_final_output' != 0, 'date']]`


**KeyError: True**

Comment: В общем в итоге пришли к тому, что без предоставления данных можно только гадать. По правилам нужно предоставить данные в вопросе )

Comment: Да нет, тут базовый синтаксис, который я забыл в силу своей неопытности. По сути нужно оставить строки из одной таблицы по условию из другой таблицы используя общий столбец **datе**. Что-то типо фильтрации.

Comment: А, так зачем тут кавычки то? `'sum_concentrat_final_output'`? Если это столбец датафрейма, то его нужно указывать вместе с датафреймом: `df_full.loc[df_full['sum_concentrat_final_output'] != 0, 'date']` Либо просто без кавычек тогда это переменная, как я выше написал в примере кода. По идее мой код должен работать без дополнительного столбца, подставьте туда свои датафреймы правильно. А ругается у вас потому что `'sum_concentrat_final_output' != 0` - это и правда `True`, с которым `loc` не знает, что делать.

Comment: Спасибо, что пытаетесь помочь.  Но так тоже не работает.
`df_test = df_test[df_test['date'] == df_full.loc[df_full['sum_concentrat_final_output'] != 0, 'date']]`
**ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects**

Comment: А, да, тут надо не `==` делать, а как-раз `merge` или `join` по `date`. Ещё как вариант через `.isin` можно сделать вместо `==`, так даже проще, наверное

Comment: Что-то типа `df_test = df_test[df_test['date'].isin(df_full.loc[df_full['sum_concentrat_final_output'] != 0, 'date')]`

Comment: ДА! СПАСИБО! ДАЙ РАСЦЕЛУЮ! Через isin сделал и все работает! Еще раз спасибо!